# Delphi 7 Automation to control AutoCAD “Invalid Class String”

Tags: delphi, automation, autocad

My application, written in Delphi 7, sends commands to AutoCAD with ActiveX. It works fine for most of my customers, but in some rare cases it cannot communicate with AutoCAD and reports the error `Invalid Class String` (AutoCAD application is running OK). The error pops up after this line:

```
AcadV := GetActiveOleObject('AutoCAD.Application');
```

I have searched this problem a lot, but I could not find a working solution.

Comment: Have you established as a definite fact that AutoCAD is installed on the machines in question *and* that they have the necessary 'AutoCAD.Application' entry in the Registry?

Comment: I checked that Autocad Application is installed and running, but I have no idea about Registry. Is there some place in Registry to check ?

Comment: I agree with @MartynA, I think that AutoCAD COM object isn't registered in the registry. The entry should be under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT somewhere. I think a reinstall of AutoCAD would likely fix the problem, or contact AutoCAD support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The small console application below shows how to check than the name of an
automation object is registered in the Windows Registry.  Automation objects need to have a registry entry in order that you can invoke them by name as in `AutoCAD.Application`

Note that the `IsRegistered`
function below does not **guarantee** that you will be able to access the object using
CreateOleObject/GetActiveOleObject  However, if the expected name is not found there
is very likely something amiss, which you may be able to fix by re-installing
the automation objects software.

```
program CheckRegConsole;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  Windows,
  Registry;

function IsRegistered(const ClassString : String) : Boolean;
var
  Reg : TRegistry;
begin
  Result := False;
  Reg := TRegistry.Create(Key_Read);
  try
    Reg.RootKey := HKey_Classes_Root;
    Result := Reg.KeyExists(ClassString);
  finally
    Reg.Free;
  end;
end;

var
  S : String;
begin
  S := 'Word.Application';  //  MS Word
  S := 'AcroExch.PDDoc';    //  Adobe Acrobat Document
  if IsRegistered(S) then
    writeln(S + ' registered')
  else
    writeln(S + ' not registered');
  readln;
end.
```

Btw, in my (limited) experience, GetActiveOleObject does not always succeed when it ought to.  So if it fails, it may be worthwhile trying CreateOleObject instead.

There is a very good book for Delphi programmers called "Delphi COM Programming"
by Eric Harmon, if you can get hold of a copy, and there are countless automation
tutorials on the internet.  See e.g. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221375(v=vs.85).aspx for the MS take on the subject.

Comment: At first, I would like to thank all of you that tried to help me. I tried all suggestions, but unfortunately the problem remains.

Comment: So, does my CheckRegConsole return "registered" or "not registered"?

Comment: CreateOleObject produces the same error with GetActiveOleObject.
I call the function listed above: IsRegistered('Autocad.Application') and returns true, no problem with registry.
Is there anything else to try?

Comment: Some time ago, I had found a small application that displayed a table with all running projects that could be controlled with ActiveX, but I cannot find it now.

Comment: I had no problems in older Windows versions. Problems started with Win7 and are more serious in Win10.
In Win7, if we turned UAC to 0, the problem used to be fixed. Now, nothing works.

Comment: Why did you not answer my q about CheckRegConsole?

Comment: I run CheckRegConsole changing one line to
S := 'AutoCAD.Application';
It returns "AutoCAD.Application' registered".

Comment: I run PowerShell and then the script
gci HKLM:\Software\Classes -ea 0| ? {$_.PSChildName -match '^\w+\.\w+$' -and (gp "$($_.PSPath)\CLSID" -ea 0)} | ft PSChildName
It is supposed to list all COM objects. It produced a very big list that I saved it in a file.
Autocad is not listed. However, Autocad is running.

Answer (score 0):

change the file api.py app function to below:

def app(self):
if self._app is None:
for v in range(35,15,-1):
try:
self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application.'+str(v), dynamic=True)
break;
except WindowsError:
try:
self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application.'+str(v)+'.1', dynamic=True)
break;
except WindowsError:
try:
self._app = comtypes.client.GetActiveObject('AutoCAD.Application.'+str(v)+'.2', dynamic=True)
break;
except WindowsError:
next;

```
    return self._app
```

Answer (score 0):

The right command for AutoCAD 1011 is

```
AcadV := GetActiveOleObject('AutoCAD.Application.18');
```

The number 18 changes for newer versions of AutoCAD (I think it is 19 for 2013 and 23 for 2021). I have created an entry where users can change this number according to their version and now my app runs for all AutoCAD versions.